# Центрирование фона в CSS

Tags: html, css

Мне необходимо задать фон body так, чтобы центр фоновой картинки совпадал с центром экрана, при этом не сжимаясь при изменении размеров экрана. Есть ли возможность реализовать такое поведение фона на чистом CSS?

Comment: Можно, вариантов много. Но прежде покажите Вашу разметку. Иначе что лучше использовать в Вашем конкретном лучше - сложно сразу сказать.

Comment: @Denis640Kb разметка состоит из открывающегося и закрывающегося тэга body)

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так?

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;

  margin: 0;
  height:100vh;
}
```